# Getting nothing from second function

Tags: python, discord

So i'm making discord bot and i'm having problems. When i change (add) item in the dictonary in `on_message()` function, in `loop()` function it just printing  `"Current mps: {}"` here part of the code:

```
import discord
import multiprocessing
import time

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

mps = {}
max_mps = 10


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.get_user(BOT_ID):
        user_id = str(message.author.id)

        if user_id in mps:
            mps.update({user_id : mps[user_id] + 1})
            #mps[user_id] += 1
            #print(mps[user_id])
        else:
            mps.update({user_id : 1})
            #mps[user_id] = 1
            #print(mps[user_id])
        #print(len(mps),"by message")
        print(mps)

def loop():
    while True:
        print("Current mps:", mps)
        print(len(mps),"by while")
        if len(mps):
            print("true")
            for id,mpss in mps.items():
                print(id,mpss)
                if mpss > 0:
                    mpss -= 1
                    print(mpss)
        time.sleep(1)

d = multiprocessing.Process(target=detect)
l = multiprocessing.Process(target=loop)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    d.start()
    l.start()
    client.run("TOKEN")
```

I try fix it with chatgpt and i'm here

Comment: You need to put `mps` in a multiprocessing manager. Otherwise, each process has its own copy of the variable.

Comment: Or you could use multithreading instead of multiprocessing.